# How to read a file in zig?

Tags: zig

How can I read a file in zig, and run over it line by line?

I did found `os.File.openRead`, but it seems old cause it says that  `container 'std.os' has no member called 'File'`.

Answer (score 29):

`std.io.reader.readUntilDelimiterOrEof` lets your read any `std.io.reader` line by line. You usually get the reader of something like a file by calling it’s `reader()` method. So for example:

```
var file = try std.fs.cwd().openFile("foo.txt", .{});
defer file.close();

var buf_reader = std.io.bufferedReader(file.reader());
var in_stream = buf_reader.reader();

var buf: [1024]u8 = undefined;
while (try in_stream.readUntilDelimiterOrEof(&buf, '\n')) |line| {
    // do something with line...
}
```

The `std.io.bufferedReader` isn’t mandatory but recommended for better performance.

Comment: I understand zig is a quite low level. None the less I am surprised it needs that may lines of code to do something quite common like reading a file into a string. Do I have to admire the low levelness each time, I want to read a file?

Comment: No, you don't have to do this. You can read a file into a preallocated buffer by calling the readFile function of a Dir object - such as std.fs.cwd().readFile(filename, buffer).

If you don't know the size of the file you can also use the readFileAlloc() function of a Dir object, passing an allocator and maximum size.

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT: This method may no longer be valid as written in Zig 0.11.0 onwards, I'll leave the original content below and update the answer at some point:**

I muddled through this by looking at the Zig library source/docs, so this might not be the most idiomatic way:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() anyerror!void {
    //  Get an allocator
    var gp = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{ .safety = true }){};
    defer _ = gp.deinit();
    const allocator = &gp.allocator;

    // Get the path
    var path_buffer: [std.fs.MAX_PATH_BYTES]u8 = undefined;
    const path = try std.fs.realpath("./src/main.zig", &path_buffer);

    // Open the file
    const file = try std.fs.openFileAbsolute(path, .{ .read = true });
    defer file.close();

    // Read the contents
    const buffer_size = 2000;
    const file_buffer = try file.readToEndAlloc(allocator, buffer_size);
    defer allocator.free(file_buffer);

    // Split by "\n" and iterate through the resulting slices of "const []u8"
    var iter = std.mem.split(file_buffer, "\n");

    var count: usize = 0;
    while (iter.next()) |line| : (count += 1) {
        std.log.info("{d:>2}: {s}", .{ count, line });
    }
}
```

The above is a little demo program that you should be able to drop into the default project created from `zig init-exe`, it'll just print out it's own contents, with a line number.

You can also do this without allocators, provided you supply the required buffers.

I'd also recommend checking out this great resource: https://ziglearn.org/chapter-2/#readers-and-writers

Note: I'm currently running a development version of Zig from master (reporting 0.9.0), but I think this has been working for the last few official releases.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore in zig 0.11.0, `no field named 'allocator' in struct`

Comment: Shut it all down! I think I've updated the code for this locally, so I'll try and get round to updating this answer, but I'll leave the old content in place for posterity.

Answer (score 2):

To open a file and get a file descriptor back
`std.os.open`

https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.6.0/std/#std;os.open

To read from the file
`std.os.read`

https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.6.0/std/#std;os.read

I can't find a .readlines() style function in the zig standard library. You'll have to write your own loop to find the `\n` characters.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a test case that shows how to **create** a file, **write** to it then **open** the same file and **read** its content.

```
const std = @import("std");
const testing = std.testing;
const expect = testing.expect;

test "create a file and then open and read it" {
    var tmp_dir = testing.tmpDir(.{}); // This creates a directory under ./zig-cache/tmp/{hash}/test_file
    // defer tmp_dir.cleanup(); // commented out this line so, you can see the file after execution finished.

    var file1 = try tmp_dir.dir.createFile("test_file", .{ .read = true });
    defer file1.close();

    const write_buf: []const u8 = "Hello Zig!";
    try file1.writeAll(write_buf);

    var file2 = try tmp_dir.dir.openFile("test_file", .{});
    defer file2.close();

    const read_buf = try file2.readToEndAlloc(testing.allocator, 1024);
    defer testing.allocator.free(read_buf);

    try testing.expect(std.mem.eql(u8, write_buf, read_buf));
}
```

Check out `fs` package [tests on Github](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/master/lib/std/fs/test.zig) or on your local machine under `<zig-install-dir>/lib/fs/test.zig`.

Also note that test allocator only works for tests. In your actual source code you need to [choose an appropriate allocator](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Choosing-an-Allocator).

Comment: Is there a way to write line by line instead of writing all the content at once at the file writing step?

Comment: Given you have a buffer, you need to find out the location of the new-line character. Then you can create a slice of your buffer and write that slice. `Reader` type has a method called `.streamUntilDelimiter` which you can use to find the slice until the delimiter (new line character in this case). I'm not aware of any utility in the standard library for slicing lines.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way I have found to read in a file in Zig. Short, clean, and functional.

@embedFile returns a compile time constant pointer to null-terminated, fixed-size array with length equal to the byte count of the file given by path. The contents of the array are the contents of the file. This is equivalent to a string literal with the file contents.

```
const std = @import("std");
const data = @embedFile("calories.txt");
const split = std.mem.split;

pub fn main() !void {
    var splits = split(u8, data, "\n");
    while (splits.next()) |line| {
        std.debug.print("{s}\n", .{line});
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a good thing to know but embedding a file is not the same thing as reading a file.

Comment: Agreed. It basically copy the file at comp time in memory. I just found it very good solution for my needs. Hopefully this addresses part of  OP questions and people getting redirected here.