# How can I write a function to iterate over the lines in a file in Zig?

Tags: zig

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68368122/how-to-read-a-file-in-zig/68369871#68369871), I'm aware of how to iterate over the lines in a file in Zig. Now I'd like to factor out a helper function that returns an iterator over the lines. I found [some code from 2021 on zigforum.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20210413234716/https://zigforum.org/t/read-file-or-buffer-by-line/317/2) (Wayback machine) via a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Zig/comments/mp083u/can_anyone_show_me_an_example_of_reading_file/) that looks like it should do exactly what I want:

```
const std = @import("std");

fn ReturnTypeOf(comptime callable_type: type) type {
    const info = @typeInfo(callable_type);
    return switch (info) {
        .Fn => info.Fn.return_type.?,
        .BoundFn => info.BoundFn.return_type.?,
        else => @compileError("unsupported type " ++ @typeName(callable_type)),
    };
}

fn ReadByLineIterator(comptime ReaderType: type) type {
    return struct {
        // Should be customizable! But also if you have lines of more than 64k you have other problems.
        pub const MaxBufferSize: usize = 64 * 1024;

        allocator: *std.mem.Allocator,
        reader: ReaderType,
        last_read: ?[]const u8,

        pub fn deinit(self: @This()) void {
            if (self.last_read) |buf|
                self.allocator.free(buf);
        }

        pub fn next(self: *@This()) !?[]const u8 {
            if (self.last_read) |buf| {
                self.allocator.free(buf);
                self.last_read = null;
            }

            const line = try self.reader.readUntilDelimiterOrEofAlloc(self.allocator, '\n', MaxBufferSize);
            self.last_read = line;
            return line;
        }
    };
}

fn readByLine(allocator: *std.mem.Allocator, file: anytype) ReadByLineIterator(ReturnTypeOf(@TypeOf(file.reader))) {
    return .{
        .allocator = allocator,
        .reader = file.reader(),
        .last_read = null,
    };
}

pub fn main() !void {
    var it = readByLine(std.heap.page_allocator, std.io.getStdIn());
    defer it.deinit();
    while (try it.next()) |buf| {
        std.debug.print("read line: \"{s}\"\n", .{buf});
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get an error when I try to compile this:

```
src/util.zig:52:110: error: no field named 'reader' in struct 'fs.file.File'
pub fn readByLine(allocator: *std.mem.Allocator, file: anytype) ReadByLineIterator(ReturnTypeOf(@TypeOf(file.reader))) {
                                                                                                             ^~~~~~
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zig/0.11.0/lib/zig/std/fs/file.zig:13:18: note: struct declared here
pub const File = struct {
                 ^~~~~~
```

Perhaps this worked in 2021 but no longer does? I find this error puzzling since it certainly looks like there's a field named `reader` in that struct!

```
pub const Reader = io.Reader(File, ReadError, read);

pub fn reader(file: File) Reader {
    return .{ .context = file };
}
```

In any case, how can I get `readByLine` to work? Ideally I'd like it to work for a `BufferedReader`. This is challenging because, so far as I can tell, there's no direct way to write the type of what `BufferedReader.reader()` returns. This is why there's the `ReturnTypeOf` shenanigans in the example code.

Comment: Yes, the field exist but it is a function. You have to call `reader()` , not `reader`. After that, there are other errors so, as often with old Zig programs found on the Web, you'll have some porting to do.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77427514/how-can-i-write-a-function-to-iterate-over-the-lines-in-a-file-in-zig#comment136503971_77427514) from bortzmeyer and some help from the [Zig Forum](https://ziggit.dev/t/help-debugging-memory-corruption-while-reading-a-file-with-a-buffered-reader-and-iterator/2203/5) I was able to get something to work. The 4096 byte buffer is hard-coded here but I'm sure it could be parameterized.

```
const std = @import("std");

const ReaderType = std.fs.File.Reader;
const BufReaderType = std.io.BufferedReader(4096, ReaderType);
const BufReaderReaderType = BufReaderType.Reader;

pub const ReadByLineIterator = struct {
    file: std.fs.File,
    reader: ReaderType,
    buf_reader: BufReaderType,
    stream: ?BufReaderReaderType,
    buf: [4096]u8,

    pub fn next(self: *@This()) !?[]u8 {
        if (self.stream == null) {
            self.stream = self.buf_reader.reader();
        }
        if (self.stream) |stream| {
            return stream.readUntilDelimiterOrEof(&self.buf, '\n');
        }
        unreachable;
    }

    pub fn deinit(self: *@This()) void {
        self.file.close();
    }
};

// Iterate over the lines in the file using a buffered reader.
// Caller is responsible for calling deinit() on returned iterator when done.
pub fn iterLines(filename: []const u8) !ReadByLineIterator {
    var file = try std.fs.cwd().openFile(filename, .{});
    var reader = file.reader();
    var buf_reader = std.io.bufferedReader(reader);

    return ReadByLineIterator{
        .file = file,
        .reader = reader,
        .buf_reader = buf_reader,
        .stream = null,
        .buf = undefined,
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
fn processLines(filename: []const u8) !void {
    var line_it = try iterLines(filename);
    defer line_it.deinit();

    while (try line_it.next()) |line| {
        std.debug.print("line: '{s}'\n", .{line});
    }
}
```