# How do I build a path relative to the exe in zig?

Tags: path, zig

I want to right a zig program that loads a file that's stored next to the exe. How can I do that?

In another language I'd:

1. Find the location of the exe.
2. Get the dirname.
3. Append the desired file name.
4. Load that file.

Answer (score 1):

I found it hard to google for solutions. Few results and didn't always work in my version of zig. Instead, I searched the zig source that ships with the compiler. Since it shows up in error filepaths, it's easy to find on your disk.

```
const fs = std.fs;
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    const file_to_print = "filename.txt";

    // Defining this type made it easier for me to understand allocating a
    // string array.
    const String = []const u8;

    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    defer _ = gpa.deinit();

    const allocator = gpa.allocator();

    // See also std.fs.selfExeDirPathAlloc.
    const exe_path = try std.fs.selfExePathAlloc(allocator);
    defer allocator.free(exe_path);
    const opt_exe_dir = std.fs.path.dirname(exe_path);

    if (opt_exe_dir) |exe_dir| {
        var paths = [_]String{ exe_dir, file_to_print };

        const file_path = try fs.path.join(allocator, &paths);
        defer allocator.free(file_path);
        std.debug.print("File location: {s}.\n", .{file_path});

        // There are a few ways to load the file (iterate over lines, etc).
        // Here we load the whole thing and print it all out:
        const file_content = std.fs.cwd().readFileAlloc(allocator, file_path, std.math.maxInt(usize)) catch {
            print("Failed: {s} \n", .{file_to_print});
            return;
        };
        defer allocator.free(file_content);
        std.debug.print("{s}\n", .{file_content});
    }
}
```

Finding `std.fs.selfExePathAlloc` and how to use `fs.path.join` were made much easier by using zig source code as an example.
This worked for me on zig 0.11.0.

*[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77446009/79125) for how to iterate over the file line-by-line.*