How to read a file to a byte array in Zig
How to read a file to a byte array in Zig?
I'd like to read the contents of a file to byte array in Zig.
I have a path to the file and I'd like to read contents of the file to  a single contiguous byte array. The file is so small that it will fit comfortably in memory.

I'd be better if you share a code section of the way you're trying

This first fetches the size of the file and uses that as max_size for readToEndAlloc. This assumes that the size of the file stays constant, that is, it doesn't change while you run this code.
const file = try std.fs.cwd().openFile(path, .{});
defer file.close();

const stat = try file.stat();
const buf: []u8 = try file.readToEndAlloc(allocator, stat.size);

Tested with Zig 0.13.0 in December 2024.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68368122/how-to-read-a-file-in-zig for line oriented reading.
